# AUCTeX Emacs TeX-quote-after-quote shortcut when \usepackage{csquotes} is in inputed file

Tags: emacs, csquotes

I load all my packages through one file which I include with `\input{loadPackages.tex}`. But with this procedure my Emacs Aquamacs preference

```
;; " expands into csquotes macros
(setq LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote "}"
      LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote "\\enquote{")
```

to automatically convert `"` into `\enquote{` doesn't work any more.

Any solution?

Comment: Just to be sure: if you manually load your packages (ie not with the input technique), this preference works ?

Comment: @Clément Yes, `\input{loadPackages.tex} \usepackage{csquotes}` works

Comment: I have a similar setup here, and it works as expected. Try this: in the document, press `C-c C-n` to force emacs to refresh its style files. Does it work then? If not, re-evaluate the `setq` form, does it work then?

Comment: Also, again just to be sure: does the preamble parsing work fine for other stuff defined in `loadPackages.tex`?

Comment: @T.Verron Yes everything as expected, just the shortcut doesn't work

Comment: Try visiting the `loadPackages.tex` file and pressing `C-u C-c C-n` there. Or deleting the file `./auto/loadPackages.el` and repeating the procedure of my first comment.

Comment: @T.Verron I tried your suggestion (refresh style on both document and deleting `./auto` folder), but still doesn't work. Could it depend on the order packages are loaded by `loadPackages.tex`?

Comment: Check `./auto/loadPackages.el` : does `"csquotes"` appear somewhere there?

Comment: @T.Verron Actually my `./auto` folder is empty. When I `C-c C-n` on `loadPackages.el` it creates the folder but I don't see any file in it...

Comment: What is the value of `TeX-parse-self`? https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html#Parsing-Files

Comment: @T.Verron My Preferences.el: `;; AUCTeX + Reftex       
(setq TeX-parse-self     t)   ; Enable parse on load 
(setq TeX-auto-save      t)   ; Enable parse on save 
(setq-default TeX-master nil) ; Query for master file <-- this one is key for this question`